# What does this Snort rule do?

Tags: network, snort

Rule-4:
alert udp $EXTERNAL_NET any
-> $HOME_NET 3333 (msg:"ET
EXPLOIT Wireshark ENTTEC
DMX Data Processing Code
Execution Attempt 1";

content:"|45
53 44 44|";

depth:4;

content:"|04|";
distance:2; within:1;
 content:"|FE
FF|";

distance:0; within:50;
content:"|FE FF|";
 distance:0;
within:50; content:"|FE|";
byte_test:1,>,11,0,relative;
classtype:attempted-user;
reference:url,www.exploitdb.
com/exploits/15898/;
reference:bid,45634; sid:2012154;
rev:2;)

Comment: [snort users manual, section 3 / writing snort rules](http://www.snort.org/assets/166/snort_manual.pdf) might help

Comment: Have you looked up the reference link in the rule?

Answer (score 1):

The rule appears to look for a specific pattern of content bytes in traffic sent to port 3333/UDP.

The goal appears to be to detect an attempt to exploit a vulnerability in Wireshark, where parsing specific traffic causes a buffer overflow on the machine parsing the traffic.  The exploit-db link in the rule shows the details of the exploit for this issue.